# Swift - Cannot pass value successfully to the ViewController that is presented next

Tags: ios, swift

I have an ItemsController and I want to pass a value to the RepostController when using `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)` to present the RepostController. I want to set the `itemId` of the RepostController to be `cell.item!.getId()`. But in the RepostController, I always get a value of 0 from the `itemId`. I have also tried to print the values. They are commented in the codes below.

I'm using Swift 4 with Xcode 10.1.

```
// ITEMS CONTROLLER

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.30, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0)]

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.30, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()


    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.refresh(sender: self)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    if ((profileId == iApp.sharedInstance.getId() && pageId == Constants.ITEMS_PROFILE_PAGE) || pageId == Constants.ITEMS_FEED_PAGE || pageId == Constants.ITEMS_STREAM_PAGE) {

        let newItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add , target: self, action: #selector(newItem))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = newItemButton

    }

    // add tableview delegate

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    // prepare for loading data

    self.showLoadingScreen()

    // start loading data

    self.loadData()

}
func showRepostButton(cell: ItemCell) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Content", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RepostController") as! RepostController

    destination.itemId = cell.item!.getId()

    print (String(cell.item!.getId())) // Whatever the correct value is (such as 20)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}

// REPOST CONTROLLER

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.30, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0)]

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.30, blue:0.30, alpha:1.0)

    textView.delegate = self
    textView.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.72, blue:0.65, alpha:1.0)

    print ("itemID:" + String(self.itemId))
}


@IBAction func cancelTap(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func repostTap(_ sender: Any) {

    self.message = self.textView.text

    send()

}
```

I need the value to be passed to the RepostController successfully.
What changes do I need to make? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show more code? A lot depends on stuff you have not shown.

Comment: I just updated it with more codes. I don't think any other codes are related to this problem. If you need more, please tell me and I will update immediately. Thanks!

Comment: How is `showRepostButton` called?  Make sure you don't have an action segue directly from the button to the repost controller in your storyboard

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem.

Comment: If the problem is solved, answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a PUSH segue in IB.  Then in the prepare(forSegue:) method:

```
if let dest = segue.destination as? YourDestinationVC {
    dest.itemId = someValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what if I want to pass a value that is from a specific cell? Like the indexPath.row of the cell?